# how does nls model work?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nls

I am trying to understand how nls model works.

Let's say I have data frame mtcars and like to do this:

```
model<-nls(mpg~disp)
```

but getting this error:

```
Error in cll[[1L]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

I've read the documentation, it says something about I have to include start parameters. Can somebody explain to me what are start parameters? Does that depend on how many features are there? How could I programmatically pick the right a and b starting points (still don't know what is the start parameter is). I'd really appreciate if some one provide some insight into how nls model works and all the different parameters? Need to know this before applying them.

I think the most important question, how do I come up with the predictor model like this one

```
y~a*(x+c)^b
```

is there a way to come up with the right side of this formula:

```
a*(x+c)^b
```

---

Comment: start parameters are the initial guesses you have to provide for the parameters you are using nls to estimate. They are the starting point of a nonlinear iterative algorithm.  If the starting values are close to the optimal values, the algorithm may tend to converge more quickly and reliably to the optimal values.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, I got that but there is data frame that has dependent and independent variable. Is there a way to come up with the formula to fit? for example, how do would you come up wiht a*(x+c)^b etc. I think that's what I am asking here.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, in other words, how do you get the equation to fit the data in R?

Comment: Do you have any subject matter knowledge of the data being fitted which leads you to a particular model?  If not, nls may not be the right tool for you.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, I am basically trying to predict resource usage (cpu, heap usage, etc) given the workload data. I am familiar with linear model but I need to explore other models so that I can pick the best predictor model. Things not always linear. I'd be good to have other choices and see which one has less error.

Comment: If you have no basis for a particular parameterized nonlinear model (functional form), you may be better off with a non-parametric approach, in which case, nls is not the tool to use. The whole idea of nls is that you know, or have a candidate, for the model, but just need to determine the numerical values of its parameters.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, Can Loess help in this case?

Comment: @user1471980 comments are not the place for a tutorial on modelling. If you have a new question on LOESS, you should do a little reading (at least wikipedia) and then post a specific question; a question on LOESS would not be related to clarifying the present question.